# Django database and migration error, ValueError: Related model 'Users.user' cannot be resolved

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, database-migration

I am facing a very very strange situation with my Django (in general). I'm using Django 2.2 and Python 3.6.7.

Every single time I create a new project, using:

```
django-admin startproject myproject
```

and trying to migrate it, I got this error :

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying admin.0004_auto_20190630_1438... OK
  Applying admin.0005_auto_20190630_1441...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Dev\Django\myproject\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Dev\Django\myproject\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Dev\Django\Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Dev\Django\Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Dev\Django\Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Dev\Django\Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Dev\Django\Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Dev\Django\Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 234, 

in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Dev\Django\Env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, 

fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Dev\Django\Env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Dev\Django\Env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Dev\Django\Env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply    
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Dev\Django\Env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 249, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "C:\Dev\Django\Env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 137, in alter_field
    super().alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, strict=strict)
  File "C:\Dev\Django\Env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 507, in alter_field
    new_db_params = new_field.db_parameters(connection=self.connection)
  File "C:\Dev\Django\Env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 966, in db_parameters
    return {"type": self.db_type(connection), "check": self.db_check(connection)}
  File "C:\Dev\Django\Env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 963, in db_type
    return self.target_field.rel_db_type(connection=connection)
  File "C:\Dev\Django\Env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 878, in target_field
    return self.foreign_related_fields[0]
  File "C:\Dev\Django\Env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 632, in foreign_related_fields
    return tuple(rhs_field for lhs_field, rhs_field in self.related_fields if rhs_field)
  File "C:\Dev\Django\Env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 619, in related_fields
    self._related_fields = self.resolve_related_fields()
  File "C:\Dev\Django\Env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 604, in resolve_related_fields
    raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model)
ValueError: Related model 'Users.user' cannot be resolved
```

this occurs everytime I try to migrate all my projects, even all old projects.

Is this some kind of django bug? or did I configure it improperly? I also use the default django settings (without even touching anything).

I messed up by this error. I cannot do any migrations to all my projects. 
I have uninstalled django and reinstalled it back, but nothing changed, I got the same error.

A few moments ago I created a custom user model (AbstractBaseUser) in my project. And it was running perfectly. But I when I try to input data to any model in the admin panel, I got error `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed` (whereas I had only one model, AbstractBaseUser model). I didn't know what to do with that, And I deleted that project.

Afterwards, I created a new project (for learning purposes), and trying migrate it, this critical serious error appeared.

Do guys have any solution to overcome this? **Please help me out of this problem**

Comment: Isn't it `users.User` (different capitalization)?